# Gnome Classic, Compiz and Panels

Tags: compiz, panel

I have compiz installed on ubuntu 14.04 running gnome classic with window decoration enabled. To enable compiz I can type `compiz --replace` but the panel at the top disappears. Does anyone know how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

If it works in Gnome as it does in Xubuntu, you need to have the Greybird theme for the bar to show.

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Then press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and run: `dconf-editor`, navigate to org > gnome > desktop > wm > preferences and change the "theme" value from "Adwaita" to "Greybird"